# What should i store as UserName from DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, dotnetopenauth

Im using DotNetOpenAuth to integrate [Google](http://www.google.com),[Yahoo](http://www.yahoo.com),[Twitter](http://www.Twitter.com) and [Facebook](http://www.Facebook.com) Logins into my application.

Now everything works as expected.

- Twitter returns -> User-name and Claim-identifier(Just Id)
- Google returns -> Email-Address, First and last Name and ID(URL+ID)
- Yahoo returns -> Email-Address, Alias and ID (Url + ID)

Also im also allowing my users to register internally so my database User table is like this:

- ID,UserName,Name,OpenID,LoginType,DisplayName

im wondering what i should be storing as User-Name, i was thinking of the ID, but i have this questions:

1. Shall i store the whole ID as User-Name ?!
2. Would it affect performance to store the whole ID(URL) as username?
3. If i extracted the ID from the Claim-Identifier would it still be unique between all 3 providers?

Comment: I would use the email address as the username. For twitter, you can just use a pseudo email such as Username@twitter (no .com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OpenID, you must use the `ClaimedIdentifier` as the ID.  Not anything else, and certainly not only a substring from the claimed identifier.  Anything else seriously compromises the security of your application.

As far as where you store it, I would recommend you keep a dedicated column for storing your claimed identifier rather than just storing it in your UserName column.  Consider this scenario:

1. A user creates an account with your web site using an OpenID `http://SomeOpenIDUrl`
2. An attacker logs in via the username/password form. He leaves the password blank but enters `http://SomeOpenIDUrl` as the username
3. The attacker successfully logs in as his victim.

A situation like the above can be mitigated in various ways of course, but the best way IMO is to keep the OpenID out of the username column so that it's completely impossible.